# Dependency failed (Puppet)

Tags: tomcat, puppet, vagrant

**Problem:** When I run puppet to provision the box the first time, I will have dependency failed errors and the files with these errors (`apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1.jar`) are not copied to their target destination. However doing the provisioning a second time there are no longer the dependency errors and all files seem to be copied correctly.

How can the dependency errors be solved without re-provisioning? Why is this happening?

**Manifest**

```
file { '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war':
  ensure => present,
  owner   => root,
  group   => root,  
  mode    => 644,   
  source => 'puppet:///modules/solr/apache-solr-3.6.1.war',
  notify => Service['tomcat'],
}

file { '/usr/share/solr':
  ensure => present,
  source => 'puppet:///modules/solr/solr',
  recurse => true,
  require => File['/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war'],
  notify => Service['tomcat'],
}

file { '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml':
  ensure => present,
  owner   => root,
  group   => root,  
  mode    => 644,   
  source => 'puppet:///modules/solr/web.xml',
  require => [ File['/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war'], File['/usr/share/solr'] ],
}

file { '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1.jar':
  ensure => present,
  owner   => root,
  group   => root,  
  mode    => 644,   
  source => 'puppet:///modules/solr/apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1.jar',
  require => File['/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war'],
  notify => Service['tomcat'],
}
```

**Error**

```
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Solr/File[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war]/ensure: defined content as'{md5}ae7997a401f9d223b097f8a88259689e'←[0m
←[1;35merr: /Stage[main]/Solr/File[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1.jar]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file on ensure: No such file or directory - /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1.jar.puppettmp_4049 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/solr/manifests/init.pp:37←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Solr/File[/usr/share/solr]/ensure: created←[0m
...
...
...
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/Service[tomcat]: Dependency File[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1.jar] has failures: true←[0m
←[0;33mwarning: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/Service[tomcat]: Skipping because of failed dependencies←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/Service[tomcat]: Triggered 'refresh' from 6 events←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Solr/File[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml]/content: content changed '{md5}1b3a494d9ddefb9bef08caa5146cfd32' to '{md5}f3b9d07f7585ef8008f2bcf0407596f2'←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Solr/File[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml]/owner: owner changed 'tomcat6' to 'root'←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Solr/File[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml]/group: group changed 'tomcat6' to 'root'←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: Finished catalog run in 18.90 seconds←[0m
```

**Directory Structure**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that puppet complains that the directory `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/` does not exist when it tries to create `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.6.1.jar`.

I suspect that this directory is created when the new `.war` get detected by tomcat, but it happens too late and you have to relaunch puppet.

So you may want to explicitely ensure creation of this dir with :

```
file
{
    '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr':
        ensure => directory,
        ;
    '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF':
        ensure => directory,
        ;
    '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib':
        ensure => directory,
        ;
}
```

(omitting the "require" because it seems that puppet creates them in the order they are defined)

I'm not a tomcat expert, but you may want to ensure that creating the dirs manually will not interfere with tomcat .war auto-detection system.

Comment: Thanks, yes creating the directories does interfere with Tomcat's auto-deployment of .war.